# Mesh networking zigbee

Tags: python, xbee

I have a mesh network with 5 routers and 1 coordinator. The data from the coordinator is sent to database in pi and then hosted to website. When i try to read the routing table information from the coordinator , i see that all routers are connected to coordinator(star network) but when i see the flow diagram on XCTU i can see the mesh network. How can i read the routing details and update on the database? the database needs to be updated as and when the routing changes. In python should i handle this?

Comment: Why do you need to read the routing details?  The mesh network is transparent to network operation.  The coordinator can discover all 5 nodes and address them directly.  Lower levels of the networking protocol handle route discovery and ensuring the message gets to the destination node.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ZDO calls that can be used to gather information on the ZigBee network topology and health.

The `Management Routing Request` call gets the routing table from each device. This lists the route through that device to an end destination - ie it will show the next hop to a final destination. By gathering these tables from all devices, you can build the routing table and map the available routes through the network.

The `Management LQI Request` call gets the neighbor table from each device. This is not strictly the routing table, but will provide the link quality for each neighbor. This is the quality of the signal received by the node. Again, by gathering this information for all devices, you can build a map of the network with link quality.

It's also worth noting that many coordinators will provide route details when they send a message. The ZDO requests will need to be polled periodically and this can generate a considerable amount of network traffic if not performed carefully.